# Execute Async methods in parallel using Task.WhenAll

Tags: parallel-processing, async-await, task

I need to insert data to my database using InsertData(). Data is being fetched using another service. The below code is executing one after one. What is the best approach to execute this in parallel.

```
var taskslist = new List<Task>();
taskslist.Add(this.database.InsertData("data1", await this.service.GetData1()));
taskslist.Add(this.database.InsertData("data2", await this.service.GetData2()));
taskslist.Add(this.database.InsertData("data3", await this.service.GetData3()));
await Task.WhenAll(taskslist);
```

Comment: Does `InsertData` return `Task`?

Comment: Yes. InsertData return Task and GetData() methods return Task<IList<model>>

Comment: What do you expect to get by trying to execute multiple inserts in parallel? This will only increase contention. `Task.WhenAll` doesn't parallelise anything either, it awaits already executing async methods to complete. *Your code* forces serial executing by using `await this.service.GetData1()` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your calls to `await` in another `async` method:

```
async Task GetAndInsert(string key, Func<Task<IList<model>>> getFunc)
    => await database.InsertData(key, await getFunc());
```

Then each can be run simultaneously:

```
var taskslist = new List<Task>();
taskslist.Add(GetAndInsert("data1", service.GetData1));
taskslist.Add(GetAndInsert("data2", service.GetData2));
taskslist.Add(GetAndInsert("data3", service.GetData3));
await Task.WhenAll(taskslist);
```

If you don't need to use the `Tasks` after they have completed, you could even pass them straight to `Task.WhenAll` rather than creating a list:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    GetAndInsert("data1", service.GetData1),
    GetAndInsert("data2", service.GetData2),
    GetAndInsert("data3", service.GetData3));
```